# A general topology textbook for a specific purpose and taste, from a specific set of choices

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm not much interested in algebraic/differential/geometric topology as **I'm more geared towards analysis**. A solid foundation for **general topology** (aka **point-set topology**) would do for now. **I can't decide on which one to choose from these set of three books** to meet my purpose. It would be really helpful if anyone can give me a **comparative study** of these books, their **strengths and weaknesses** and his/her **overall experience** **(feel free to describe your experience even if you've covered only one or two of these)**, so I can have a better understanding of what these books offer and whether it fits my bill.

**(1)** *General Topology* - **Stephen Willard**

**(2)** *Introduction to topology and modern analysis* - **G. F. Simmons**

**(3)** *Topology* - **James Munkres**

I prefer the books with **lots of remarks, notes, discussion and strong sets of exercises that make me think**, over the *"facts only, ma'am"*-type of dry books. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you can or can't pick one of these three books? If you can't, why are you interested in them?

Comment: Sorry I meant that I want to pick one of them but don't know which one fits my bill the best

Comment: Maybe you have done that already, but I'd recommend to look around whether you can find previews (author page/ Google books/ ...) of these, so you can look at the style to see whether you like it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with (1), but I am familiar with (2) and (3). Munkres' book is certainly geared as a 'standard' introduction to topology, which is point-set topology and then elements of algebraic topology, i.e. the fundamental group, surfaces, etc. (2) is certainly geared towards analysis. Simmons is an excellent author, and while I've never studied from his book (just thumbed through it a few times), it's definitely more focused. Simmons tends to write pretty good books though, and a pdf of it is readily available (just google his name), so you might try that out.

Comment: @AlfredYerger Thank you for your reply. Would you be kind enough to elaborate what you mean by *focused*? i.e. focused to what?

Comment: Simmons' concern is clearly to help you study Banach spaces, algebras of operators, etc. The kinds of things that arise in various branches of analysis. Munkres does not have anything like this. He takes the reader through the general notions of topology. If you go through Munkres, you'll be thoroughly well rounded in the language o topology, and that's not a bad thing, but the only treatment you'll see (for example) of topologies of the kinds of spaces you see in analysis will be in 1 chapter on product topologies, whereas Simmons' will spend much more time on this issue.

Comment: @AlfredYerger Thank you! That's extremely helpful.

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily worthwhile to learn point-set topology in a topology book. It can be learned instead in an analysis book. If you've already studied metric spaces elsewhere, then I would suggest *Real and Functional Analysis* by Lang. Otherwise, you can learn about metric spaces first in Apostol or Rudin's introductory analysis books.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has mentioned Albert Wilansky's [**Topology for Analysis**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486469034), especially given that a few years ago a Dover reprint appeared (which should have raised its visibility). Wilansky's book had the unfortunate fate of appearing the same year that Willard's much better known book appeared (in 1970), and just a few years before Munkres' widely adopted (in the U.S., at least) book appeared (in 1975), so during the 1970s and 1980s it was not as well known as the other two.

Comment: I had the Simmons text as a student. It's a good choice for the relation between topology and analysis. And I would echo the other comment(s) about the Rudin books. Another good one, but narrower in scope  is A Hilbert Space Problem Book by Halmos, which is an introductory text on Hilbert space in which almost every result is stated as an exercise. (Answers are in the back!).

Answer (score 0):

You won't like Willard, it's for serious students of point set topology with little devoted to spaces analyists use.

Answer (score 0):

This book is geared at probably a lower level than the ones mentioned, but Mendelson's [Introduction To Topology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486663523) introduces the abstract definitions of a topological space as a generalization of $\mathbb R^n$ and metric spaces in general.

Additionally:

1. It will give you the requisite subjects to understand the topology necessary for basic analysis.
2. It is is also very short, which seems important.

I'm only familiar with Munkres, but it is a huge reference text dealing with many topological considerations not immediately necessary for most analysis. I think that Mendelson's book would be a bare-boned introduction, and give you enough inisight to look up, say Urysohn's Lemma, in a larger and more detailed reference text.

Unlike Simmon's there is not so much of a functional analysis bent here, but I think any standard text on functional analysis would cover the basic topological considerations, which will be comprehensible after a reasonable introduction, where you can really learn the topology that you are interested in. In my opinion, this is a better route anyhow, the "deep" general topology did not help me at all with Functional Analysis, learning topology from a functional analysis book did, though.